# Is it possible that Laravel Scheduler is skipping commands?

Tags: laravel, schedule

I have a Kernel.php having many different command defined like the following:

**(Laravel v5.5.*)**

```
<?php

.....

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $fileCronLog = '/var/log/laravel-scheduler.log';

    $schedule->command('do:something params...')->everyFiveMinutes()->appendOutputTo($fileCronLog);
    $schedule->command('do:something params...')->everyMinute()->appendOutputTo($fileCronLog);
    $schedule->command('do:something params...')->everyMinute()->appendOutputTo($fileCronLog);
    $schedule->command('do:something params...')->everyMinute()->appendOutputTo($fileCronLog);
    $schedule->command('do:something params...')->everyMinute()->appendOutputTo($fileCronLog);
    $schedule->command('do:something params...')->everyMinute()->appendOutputTo($fileCronLog);
    $schedule->command('do:something params...')->everyTenMinutes()->appendOutputTo($fileCronLog);
    $schedule->command('do:something params...')->everyFiveMinutes()->appendOutputTo($fileCronLog);
    $schedule->command('do:something params...')->everyTenMinutes()->appendOutputTo($fileCronLog);
    $schedule->command('do:something params...')->everyThirtyMinutes()->appendOutputTo($fileCronLog);

    .......
```

I have noticed that sometimes it is like that some process/commands do not start at all...

And that matches with the commands with less frequency like:
`everyTenMinutes`, `everyThirtyMinutes`.....

I'm supposing  that the when the crontab start the Laravel `schedule:run`, Laravel possibly queues internally all the scheduled command... and maybe the first commands take longer than one minute to process... so when it's time for a command `everyTenMinutes` the time has passed and Laravel skip the execution....

Is this the case? Or maybe Laravel just give up processing scheduling after some time if overloaded?

I have already noticed that Laravel doesn't fork the php process but sequentially executes them. And in the past I've solved this by parallelising executions of some commands directly in the crontab...

How can I overcome this? Is there a way or option I can leverage on directly form the Framework?

Comment: Did you have a look at queues? https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues

Comment: I'm using scheduling not queues. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling

Comment: Yes I understand, but queues help long running tasks run async. Not blocking the other tasks.

Comment: Thanks. But this is not the point of my question. I want to understand why it behaves like that. Also I noticed tha tin laravel 6 has been added this: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/scheduling#background-tasks

Comment: Also the ->runInBackground() method seems available already on my version core 5.5 but not yet documented...